# On which axis do we measure angle of attack and airspeed?

Tags: wing

The lift value depends on the relative airspeed of the plane. That's what every website says without anymore explainations.

But as we are talking about lift, are we talking about the relative speed ONLY on the axis of the chord line of the airfoil ? Or the relative speed, not related to any particular axis ?

Now about angle of attack (AOA ):

Is the AOA measured on a specific axis ? Or is it the absolue angle between the airspeed Vector and the chord Line ? 
Or with other words : does AOA = 20° when the plane is on a 20° side slip ?? That's seems wrong to me but if we relate to the words of wikipedia for example thats what is being said.

Answer (score 2):

Airspeed is always the total magnitude of the free-stream incident on the wing/airplane. In zero sideslip, angle of attack is exactly the angle between free-stream and body x-axis (could be chord for an isolated wing). In non-zero sideslip, it's nuanced; see below.

By industry standard (Ref. *Etkins*, Dynamics of Flight; *Stevens*, Aircraft Control and Simulation), the angle of attack ($\alpha$) and the angle of sideslip ($\beta$) are defined as Euler rotation from the coordinate axis attached to the free-stream such that the speed vector is $\begin{bmatrix}V_a & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$, where $V_a$ is the airspeed magnitude, to the body frame (where x-axis aligns with the chord):

$$\begin{bmatrix}u_a \\ v_a \\ w_a\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha\cos\beta & -\cos\alpha\sin\beta & -\sin\alpha \\
\sin\beta & \cos\beta & 0 \\
\sin\alpha\cos\beta & -\sin\alpha\sin\beta & \cos\alpha
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}V_a \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

where $u_a$, $v_a$, $w_a$ are the incident speeds in the body frame.

Simplify, and we have:

$$\alpha = \tan^{-1}\frac{w_a}{u_a}$$

$$\beta = \sin^{-1}\frac{v_a}{V_a}$$

[image: AOA and AOS defn]

*(Image Ref. Etkins, Dynamics of Flight)*

Note that when sideslip is small (whereby $\cos{\beta}\approx1$), we can reduce the above to:

$$\alpha \approx \sin^{-1}\frac{w_a}{V_a}$$

Therefore, taking angle of attack as the projected angle between chord and free-stream is pretty darn good.

Comment: That's awesome ! Thank you very much.
Curious that all the websites are went to did not talk about that.
I understood, thank you very much.

Comment: @Anselme See the updated last paragraph. This clears up why most people don't go to the nuance.

Comment: Yep, I just saw it.
I am running a flight simulation I made and I was computing the lift while always considering the sideslip as 0.
But that's completely wrong at sometimes, performing dynamic stalls for example.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit to confident about your answer.
But something still doesnt make sense to me.
Let's take an extreme case where the plane is 90° from the relative airspeed.
Then w is 0 and the angle of attack (alpha) will still be 0, multiplied by the relative velocity squared, this gives us a prettygood amount of lift,as if it was flying forward.
But as no airflow is going in the chord direction NO LIFT is generated.
So our model is broken. Do we need to take the velocity parallel to the wind chord ?

Comment: @Anselme You're saying there's a 90deg sideslip? Put it to a wind tunnel and you'll see how much lift there is (in CL). Very small!

Comment: I am using this curve to get the CL from the AOA : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack#/media/File:Lift_curve.svg
I know there must be 0 lift with 90° sideslip. But using the AOA given by your formula and the fact we must use the "total magnitude of the free airstream" we get the same lift value as if the plane was going forward.
So the question, I am asking again : in those equations and curves, HOW is aoa measured ? When the sideslip is 90° I should compute my lift with ONLY the AOA value projected on the xz plane, otherwise it does not makes sense...

Comment: I'm in a simulation so I need to COMPUTE the lift given my wing orientation and the relative airflow.
If I measure the AOA as you said, and if I use the lift-to-aoa curve I found, it's total wrong, as I just explained why. 

I think I will stay on measuring the projected AOA and the projected airspeed along the body. Im sorry maybe I'm not explaining well but I think we are not understanding each other.

Comment: @Anselme First, that's just a sample curve. Your wingbody will be definitely different. Second, that curve is for small sideslip value for that sample wing. At extreme sideslip, you will most definitely have considerably different characteristics. Third, even Level D  simulators for high AOA fighters are only good up to around 30 deg sideslip and 40-50 AOA. The aerodynamic data are carefully gathered from wind tunnel and flight testing.

Comment: ok thank you for the informations. As it is a simulation of course I am not trying to make the next airforce training software. I must approximate things and thus using this curve has given me really cool flying results at low speeds, I managed to reproduce the same flight characteristics of the sopwith Camel. Same stall speed, same cruise speed, all of that without hardcoding anything. So what I am doing is far of being completely out of reality.

Comment: @Anselme I suggest you take a look at this video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeGdQA76SVg&list=PL_onPhFCkVQgZAwQ6arEynypDUWfZOGXf&index=71.

Answer (score 0):

Angle of attack is always measured as the angle between the chord line and the relative wind.  Different aircraft orientations will cause differences in angle of attack between the two or more wings on an airplane or the rotor on a helicopter.  For example, stalling an airplane while in uncoordinated flight can lead to a spin as the inner wing achieves a greater angle of attack than the outer wing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
"Angle of attack is always measured as the angle between the chord line and the relative wind."

So that means a plane yawing 20° from the flight path while being straight level and maintaining sufficient speed will be stalling ?? That does not make any sense to me.

Comment: It might be stalling, but it might not.  It depends on the AoA.  The yaw angle is not the same as AoA.  (which has already been defined)

Comment: It has been defined  by : "Angle of attack is always measured as the angle between the chord line and the relative wind".

So if the relative wind comes from a 30° yaw angle, then AOA is the SAME as yaw angle.

Or maybe the definiton of the AOA works only with 2D vectors and not 3D one ?

Comment: @Anselme, Ok, sorry...  I see where your confusion is now, and perhaps I wasn't clear. AoA is not a measurement of spanwise flow, it is a measurement of the angle of flow that is parallel to the chord.  In other words, you would see this angle from a side view, but not a planform view.  (Reference figures in other answer)  Does this make sense?

Comment: Nice, now all is clear ! Thanks